# DataGridView edits only the last column, previous data are empty

Tags: c#, datagridview, ping

I have problem with the `DataGridView`. I have in the DB table saved two IP addresses. I load these columns and make `Async Ping` call.

I would like to show the results in the `DataGridView`. But when all processes end, the results show only for the second column. Previous columns are empty even after it successfully ran.

I tried to do it in many ways but the results are always the same. Data are showing only for the last running step and previous columns with ping results are overwritten to empty.
Can someone advise me?

Thanks a lot, here is my code:

```
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void VPN_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=CZPRGVMSLSQL01;Initial Catalog=TOOL;User ID=sa;Password=***");
    da = new SqlDataAdapter("select STORE,servername,NAS from stores where country=" + MyClass.MyClass1.ReturnCountry() + " order by store", conn);
    dt = new DataTable();

    da.Fill(dt);

    dataGridView1.DataSource=dt;

    foreach(DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
    {

        if (row.IsNewRow)
        {
            continue;
        }
        count2 = 1;
        string data = row.Cells["servername"].Value.ToString();
        string datanas = row.Cells["NAS"].Value.ToString();

        // string data = (string)dataGridView1[3, Row].Value.ToString();
        Ping ping = new Ping();
        i++;
        ping.SendAsync(datanas, 2000, row);

        ping.PingCompleted += new PingCompletedEventHandler(ping_PingCompleted);

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3);    
    }

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
    {

        if (row.IsNewRow)
        {
            continue;
        }
        count2 = 2;
        string data = row.Cells["servername"].Value.ToString();
        string datanas = row.Cells["NAS"].Value.ToString();

        // string data = (string)dataGridView1[3, Row].Value.ToString();
        Ping ping = new Ping();
        i++;
        ping.SendAsync(data, 2000, row);
        ping.PingCompleted += new PingCompletedEventHandler(ping_PingCompleted);

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3);
    }
}


void ping_PingCompleted(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
{

    var reply = e.Reply;

    DataGridViewRow row = e.UserState as DataGridViewRow;

    if (reply != null && row.Index > -1 )
    {

        if (reply.Status.ToString() == "Success")
        {
            dataGridView1[count2, row.Index].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
            dataGridView1[count2, row.Index].Value = reply.Status;
        }
        else
            dataGridView1[count2, row.Index].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;

        dataGridView1[count2, row.Index].Value = reply.Status;
    }
    else if (row.Index>-1)
    {
        dataGridView1[count2, row.Index].Value = Color.Red;
        dataGridView1[count2, row.Index].Value = "Unexpected error";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see is that you are counting on a single variable `count2` to determine which column to access in your `PingCompleted` handler. This logic fails because by the time the first set of `Ping` objects run (expecting `count2==1`), your second loop will have already executed and set `count2=2`.

To fix, instead of sending the entire `row` into `ping.SendAsync`, just send the desired cell.

```
// count2 = 1;
// ...
ping.SendAsync(datanas, 2000, row.Cells["servername"]);

// count2 = 2;
// ...
ping.SendAsync(data, 2000, row.Cells["NAS"]);
```

Then modify your `PingCompleted` like so:

```
void ping_PingCompleted(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)//, int column)
{
    var reply = e.Reply;

    DataGridViewCell cell = e.UserState as DataGridViewCell;

    if (reply != null && cell.RowIndex > -1)
    {
        if (reply.Status.ToString() == "Success")
        {
            cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
        }
        else
        {
            cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }

        cell.Value = reply.Status;
    }
    else if (cell.RowIndex > -1)
    {
        cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
        cell.Value = "Unexpected error";
    }
}
```

Just be sure that you are sending the correct cell and data. From what I can tell, you are passing the NAS cell string value into an Async method where you'd hope to compare against a cell of column indexed at 1 (not the NAS column) and vice versa. I'm unable to test if this logic is correct or reversed, so keep an eye on that.